# Android: change links color in a webvieww

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, webview

I have a webview that displays remote HTML content formatted using a local css file.
In my css file I force the backgroung color to black, but it makes links not easy to read because of their blue color.
How can I change those links color from my css file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the anchor tags just by addressing the achor element in the css file.

```
a{
  color:White;
 }
```

This would change all your links to white on the page hope this is what you were looking for and good luck.